# CSS 3D Effect doesn't work in Mozilla FireFox

Tags: css, 3d, hover, flip, box

When you visit my Google Drive document at https://goo.gl/u6p82Y with Google Chrome or the Opera browser the link's hover effect works fine.
But in Mozilla Firefox browser the hover effect doesn't work.
What must I change?

```
.flip3D {
width: 200px;
height: 120px;
margin: auto;
float: left;
}

.flip3D > .front {
position: absolute;
-webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
-moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
width: 200px;
height: 120px;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
-moz-transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
}


.flip3D > .back {
position: absolute;
-webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);
-moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);
width: 200px;
height: 120px;
backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
-moz-transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
 }

 .flip3D:hover >.front {
-webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg);
-moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
 }

.flip3D:hover > .back {
-webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
-moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different values for `-webkit-` and `-moz-`.

Change this...

```
.flip3D:hover >.front {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg); /* <-- WRONG */
 }
```

to this...

```
.flip3D:hover >.front {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg);
 }
```

Working demo...

```css
.flip3D {
width: 200px;
height: 120px;
margin: auto;
float: left;
}

.flip3D > .front {
position: absolute;
-webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
-moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
width: 200px;
height: 120px;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
-moz-transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
}


.flip3D > .back {
position: absolute;
-webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);
-moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);
width: 200px;
height: 120px;
backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
-moz-transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
 }

 .flip3D:hover >.front {
-webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg);
-moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg);
 }

.flip3D:hover > .back {
-webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
-moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="myMain">
 
  <div class="flip3D">
   <div class="back color1">
   
    <h4>000000 Available</h4>
    <button class="btn btn-default myDefult">View</button><br/>
    <button class="btn btn-success mySuccess">Post your Job</button>
    
  </div>
   <div class="front color2">
    <h4>Web Development</h4>
    <i class="fa fa-laptop myFclass"></i>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="flip3D">
   <div class="back color2">
   <h4>000000 Available</h4>
    <button class="btn btn-default myDefult">View</button><br/>
    <button class="btn btn-success mySuccess">Post your Job</button>
   
   </div>
   <div class="front color1"><h4>Desktop Application</h4>
   <i class="fa fa-desktop myFclass"></i>
   </div>
  </div>
  
 <div class="flip3D">
  <div class="back color1"><h4>000000 Available</h4>
    <button class="btn btn-default myDefult">View</button><br/>
    <button class="btn btn-success mySuccess">Post your Job</button></div>
  <div class="front color2"><h4>Android & Mobile</h4>
  <i class="fa fa-mobile myFclass"></i>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="flip3D">
  <div class="back color2"><h4>000000 Available</h4>
    <button class="btn btn-default myDefult">View</button><br/>
    <button class="btn btn-success mySuccess">Post your Job</button></div>
  <div class="front color1"><h4>Data Science & Analytics</h4>
  <i class="fa fa-table myFclass"></i>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="flip3D">
  <div class="back color1"><h4>000000 Available</h4>
    <button class="btn btn-default myDefult">View</button><br/>
    <button class="btn btn-success mySuccess">Post your Job</button></div>
  <div class="front color2"><h4>Engineering & Architecture</h4>
   <i class="fa fa-building myFclass"></i>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="flip3D">
  <div class="back color2"><h4>000000 Available</h4>
    <button class="btn btn-default myDefult">View</button><br/>
    <button class="btn btn-success mySuccess">Post your Job</button></div>
  <div class="front color1"><h4>Design & Creative</h4>
   <i class="fa fa-skyatlas myFclass"></i>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="flip3D">
  <div class="back color2"><h4>000000 Available</h4>
    <button class="btn btn-default myDefult">View</button><br/>
    <button class="btn btn-success mySuccess">Post your Job</button></div>
  <div class="front color1"><h4>Sales & Marketing</h4>
   <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart myFclass"></i>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="flip3D">
  <div class="back color1"><h4>000000 Available</h4>
    <button class="btn btn-default myDefult">View</button><br/>
    <button class="btn btn-success mySuccess">Post your Job</button></div>
  <div class="front color2"><h4>Legal</h4>
   <i class="fa fa-gavel myFclass"></i>
  
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="flip3D">
  <div class="back color2"><h4>000000 Available</h4>
    <button class="btn btn-default myDefult">View</button><br/>
    <button class="btn btn-success mySuccess">Post your Job</button></div>
  <div class="front color1"><h4>Apparel & Fashion</h4>
   <i class="fa fa-female myFclass"></i>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="flip3D">
  <div class="back color1"><h4>000000 Available</h4>
    <button class="btn btn-default myDefult">View</button><br/>
    <button class="btn btn-success mySuccess">Post your Job</button></div>
  <div class="front color2"><h4>Game Development</h4>
   <i class="fa fa-gamepad myFclass"></i>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 
 <div class="flip3D">
  <div class="back color2"><h4>000000 Available</h4>
    <button class="btn btn-default myDefult">View</button><br/>
    <button class="btn btn-success mySuccess">Post your Job</button></div>
  <div class="front color1"><h4>Music & Audio</h4>
   <i class="fa fa-headphones myFclass"></i>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 
 <div class="flip3D">
  <div class="back color1"><h4>000000 Available</h4>
    <button class="btn btn-default myDefult">View</button><br/>
    <button class="btn btn-success mySuccess">Post your Job</button></div>
  <div class="front color2"><h4>Video & Animation</h4>
  <i class="fa fa-film myFclass"></i>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 
 <div class="flip3D">
  <div class="back color1"><h4>000000 Available</h4>
    <button class="btn btn-default myDefult">View</button><br/>
    <button class="btn btn-success mySuccess">Post your Job</button></div>
  <div class="front color2"><h4>Accounting & Consulting</h4>
   <i class="fa fa-money myFclass"></i>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 
 <div class="flip3D">
  <div class="back color2"><h4>000000 Available</h4>
    <button class="btn btn-default myDefult">View</button><br/>
    <button class="btn btn-success mySuccess">Post your Job</button></div>
  <div class="front color1"><h4>Admin & Support</h4>
   <i class="fa fa-user myFclass"></i>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="flip3D">
  <div class="back color1"><h4>000000 Available</h4>
    <button class="btn btn-default myDefult">View</button><br/>
    <button class="btn btn-success mySuccess">Post your Job</button></div>
  <div class="front color2"><h4>Media & Modeling</h4>
   <i class="fa fa-star myFclass"></i>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="flip3D">
  <div class="back color2"><h4>000000 Available</h4>
    <button class="btn btn-default myDefult">View</button><br/>
    <button class="btn btn-success mySuccess">Post your Job</button></div>
  <div class="front color1"><h4>Online Doctor</h4>
   <i class="fa fa-user-md myFclass"></i>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="flip3D">
  <div class="back color1"><h4>000000 Available</h4>
    <button class="btn btn-default myDefult">View</button><br/>
    <button class="btn btn-success mySuccess">Post your Job</button></div>
  <div class="front color2"><h4>Event Management</h4>
  <i class="fa fa-trophy myFclass"></i>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="flip3D">
  <div class="back color2"><h4>000000 Available</h4>
    <button class="btn btn-default myDefult">View</button><br/>
    <button class="btn btn-success mySuccess">Post your Job</button></div>
  <div class="front color1"><h4>Writing & Translation</h4>
  <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o myFclass"></i>
  
  </div>
 </div>

</div>
```

As a side note, you should be including non-prefixed versions of all of your transforms and transitions too. eg.

```
-webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg);
-moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg);
transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg);
```